# Winforms Prevent to open same forms Dynamic

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, dynamic

If i click to button , my below code works very well.

```
if (Application.OpenForms["StockCardForm"] == null)
  {
            var stockCardForm = new StockCardForm();
            stockCardForm.MdiParent = this;
            stockCardForm.Show();
  }
  else
  Application.OpenForms["StockCardForm"].Focus();
```

Instead of "**StockCardForm**" how can i give form name dynamic  or how can i prevent to open same forms second time as dynamic ?

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if there are any forms of some type already open and then do whatever you want.

```
if (!Application.OpenForms.OfType<StockCardForm>().Any())
{
    var  form  = new StockCardForm();
    form.Show();
}
else
    Application.OpenForms.OfType<StockCardForm>().First().Focus();
```

Comment: Than i need a class and class parameter will be form name right ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: How can i write a class generic and give formname and use/run your code ?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, what you want is to open some form, and the form to open is determined dynamically? Example, have two buttons and each one runs the same code but opens different forms?

Comment: Forget what i said please . I want to learn lastly. What is the difference between your code and my code.I can not see very much advantages to use your code.Your code and my code seems almost same.

Comment: Try debugging and looking into the OpenForms collection and you will see what is the main difference between the code. Also, with my code is very easy to create a generic method such as OpenForm<T> and just replace the OfType<StockCardForm> for OfType<T> and it will work for all other forms you may have. There are more differences, but I think that with a little debug and research you'll easily find what they are.